# TFS Build log shows that the Test Impact match pattern is set to "/build/*.*/*.dll" not '*.exe"

Tags: tfs

I started a new project in VS 2013 and TFS 2013. After doing a little coding I ran some tests and created test cases in the Test Manager. The tests pass and the Test result files show the impact XML files attached. However, all the subsequent builds show no Tests Impacted. After checking the build logs I see that the Test Impact entry has a Match pattern that ends in:
"\bin***.dll", but the application is a windows form app.

Is there something I have missed in setting up the project that would cause this?

This is the output log section:

```
...
Run VS Test Runner00:00:00
There were no matches for the search pattern ...\bin\**\*test*.dll
There were no matches for the search pattern ...\bin\**\*test*.appx
Run optional script after Test Runner00:00:00
Inputs
EnvironmentVariables:
Enabled: True
Arguments:
FilePath:
Outputs
Result: 0
Get Impacted Tests00:00:00
There were no matches for the search pattern ...\bin\**\*.dll
A baseline build could not be located. Test impact analysis will not be 
performed for this build.
Publish Symbols
...
```

Comment: That entry should tell Test Impact Analysis where your tests are located. Not the application that is being impacted. How is you Unit Test project named?

Comment: At this point I am only building the UI and don't have any unit tests, just manual tests run via the Test Manager. Even when I change every method on the form I still don't see any tests impacted. I have this working for other projects, so must have done something different this time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. For the Test Impact Analysis the build must have a drop location: The "copy output to the server" option does not count as a "drop location"!